# Rails 4.0.0.beta ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):

Tags: rails-routing, ruby-on-rails-4

I've created simple rails app. In development mode i'd got typical "Welcome page" but in production mode had error **ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/")** until created controller and set root route. Why i can't see "Welcome page" in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The welcomes controller is only for development. Here is the pull request that added it stating that it only works in the development environment:

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/8468